# Motion Events in android

Tags: android, instrumentation

This is the code for motion events in my instrumentation testing.

```
   long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

   long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

   MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100,100, 0);

   MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
   MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 100, 100, 0);

   instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);

   instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event2);
```

And the following is the error iam getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ni.fastflip.test.FastFlipWebviewTest.test(FastFlipWebviewTest.java:28)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:205)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:195)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:175)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

Can any body suggest me what to do please

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `android.app.Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();`
Inside `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` before sending pointer syncs or other classes, which have possibility to retrieve instruments instance.

Complete sample [here](http://softteco.blogspot.com/2011/02/touch-hold-swipe-release-gesture.html)

Answer (score 0):

Which ones of these lines is line 28? thats where the null pointer exep was.

Use

```
if(whatever==null){ Log.d("tag","whatever was null"); }
```

to figure out which reference was null on line 28 if you have to.

Comment: Null pointer Exception is at 
 instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);
event is null here.What do i do now?

Answer (score 0):

If the top of the stack trace indicates the null pointer is on this line:

```
instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event);
```

Then that means that `instrumentation` is null, not `event`. If event was null then the null pointer would happen inside of the `sendPointerSync` method or further up the stack.